# How to insert into mysql db two items with php

Tags: php, mysql, insert, items

How to insert two texts (i.e. header and paragraph text) into mysql db with PHP. At this point, I know how to insert just one.

in db they are called name and mtext

Here is the code:

```
<?php 

require_once 'app/init.php';

if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $mtext = trim($_POST['mtext']);

    if(!empty($name)) {
        $addedQuery = $db->prepare("
            INSERT INTO items (name, mtext, user, done, created)
            VALUES (:name, :mtext, :user, 0, NOW())
        ");

        $addedQuery->execute([
            'name' => $name,
            'mtext' => $mtext,
            'user' => $_SESSION['user_id']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you enter already 2 name and user,so simply extend your database with adding new columns and then add a new variable in the values part for every column and fill it in the execute

Comment: You can put a comma after the first row and add a second one. Something like this: VALUES (:name1, :mtext1, :user1, 0, NOW()),(:name2, :mtext2, :user2, 0, NOW())